# ngbDatepicker: Disble Dates not working when calling outside contructor

Tags: angular

I am trying to disable specific dates on click of calendar icon but it is not working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-enable-specific-dates?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-popup.html

Comment: have a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypqcv4

Comment: your stackblitz looks work :?

Comment: I also achieved with in constructor , but I want to execute this logic onClick function

Comment: Inside the function that logic not working. There I am facing issue